# Android kotlin two way databinding on androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager::currentTab

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I've tried tutorials on the Internet to add adapter on `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager` to get two way databinding on current tab.
I arrived to that adapter

```kotlin
// adapter file
@BindingAdapter("currentTab")
@JvmStatic
fun setTab(pager: ViewPager, itemLiveData: MutableLiveData<Int>) {
   itemLiveData.value?.let {

        if (pager.currentItem != it) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(it, true)
        }
    }
}

@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "currentItem")
@JvmStatic
fun getTab(pager: ViewPager) = pager.currentItem
```

```xml
<!-- layout file -->
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    app:adapter="@{viewModel.adapter}"
    app:currentTab="@={viewModel.currentItem}"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tabLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

When I try to build the app, I got this error (with the `--stacktrace` option) :

`Could not find event 'currentItemAttrChanged' on View type 'androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager'`

I can't find any tutorials/answer so I ask here if anyone have an answer to that.
Thanks

**EDIT :**
I tried with `@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "currentTab")` but it give me the same kind of error : `Could not find event 'currentTabAttrChanged' on View type 'androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager'`.

The problem is that I don't know the event name call when `currentTab` change.

Answer (score 0):

Every attribute you want bindable must match the name of a `@BindingAdapter`.
Gradle could not find `@BindingAdapter("currentTab")`.

You can either
- write `currentTab` BindingAdapter + its [InverseBindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingAdapter) to observe it.
- or a quick solution: bind a simple `ViewPager.OnPageChangedListener` and implement from it

```kotlin
@BindingAdapter("onPageChangeListener")
fun ViewPager.bindOnPageChangeListener(listener: ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener) {
    addOnPageChangeListener(listener)
}
```

```xml
<!-- layout file -->
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    app:adapter="@{viewModel.adapter}"
    app:onPageChangeListener="@{viewModel.onPageChangeListener}"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tabLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

Comment: not being able to use this app:onPageChangeListener even after creating @BindingAdapter

Answer (score 0):

2-way binding always required 3 adapters. The first (regular) one hauls data from vm to the view, the second (inverse) hauls the opposite way and the third (event) one tells the second when to fire. `@InverseBindingAdapter` has 2 attributes: `attribute` and `event`. If you don't specify the latter, it defaults to attribute name + "AttrChanged". Because it cannot work without the third. That's what the error message is saying.

ViewPager doesn't provide specialized "onPageChanged" listener. Instead, it has 3-fold `OnPageChangeListener`. But it's trivial to create a required event:

```
@BindingAdapter("currentTabAttrChanged")
public static void currentTabAttrChanged(@NonNull ViewPager viewpagerView, @Nullable InverseBindingListener listener) {
    if (listener != null) {
        viewpagerView.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                listener.onChange();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to be notified from inside a ViewModel about page changes in the ViewPager.  In that case, as Benoit Guina pointed out, you can bind the OnPageChangeListener like so.

In your xml file, represent your view pager like so:

```
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:setPageChangeListener="@{myViewModel.pageChangeCallback}" />
```

Notice that we have a custom property called setPageChangeListener. The value supplied to that property is obtained from our view model. We define the custom property in our BindingAdapters file like so:

```
/**
 * set listener for view pager changes
 */
@BindingAdapter("setPageChangeListener")
fun ViewPager2.setPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener: ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback) {
    registerOnPageChangeCallback(pageChangeListener)
}
```

Finally we define the listener in our view model. Because the listener is in the view model, it can modify properties in that view model when a change to the view pager happens.

```
/**
 * In the View Model
 */
val currentPageLiveData = MutableLiveData(0)

val pageChangeCallback = object: ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        super.onPageSelected(position)
        currentPageLiveData.value = position
    }
}
```